# Moodle course content from renderer function "coursecat_coursebox_content"

Tags: moodle, microdata

I hope you will understand my english clearly. So my question is :

I'm new to moodle, I just start testing in local. So when the course is show on the first page, its appear with TITLE and CONTENT (Description and Teachers).
And what I want to do is to seperate the CONTENT to have a Description seperate from the Teachers when rendering. The idea is to use microdata from schema so that I can apply a different itemprop to "Description" and a different itemprop to "Teachers".

Right now when I applied microdata to the renderer its grabs the Description and Teachers and put all together.

Currently structure:

```
$content .= html_writer::start_tag('div', array('class' => 'content'));

        $content .= html_writer::start_tag('span', array('itemprop' => 'description'));

            $content .= $this->coursecat_coursebox_content($chelper, $course);

        $content .= html_writer::end_tag('span'); // .span description

    $content .= html_writer::end_tag('div'); // .content
```

now what I want is something like this:

```
$content .= html_writer::start_tag('div', array('class' => 'content'));

        $content .= html_writer::start_tag('span', array('itemprop' => 'description'));

            $content .= $this->coursecat_coursebox_content("description of a course");

        $content .= html_writer::end_tag('span'); // .span description

        $content .= html_writer::start_tag('span', array('itemprop' => 'creator'));

            $content .= $this->coursecat_coursebox_content("Teachers of a course");

        $content .= html_writer::end_tag('span'); // .span creator

    $content .= html_writer::end_tag('div'); // .content
```

Thank you in advance, I'm using moodle 2.8. And this microdata I'm applying it in the file renderer.php locate at http://localhost/moodle/course/renderer.php

Comment: The goal of this is to apply MICRODATA to moodle course. I will appreciate any help on how I can make it possible.